# Mobile redirect with .htaccess but for root domain only

Tags: .htaccess

I purchased a mobile site theme from a developed on ThemeForest.net and he suggested I speak with the community here about .htaccess.  I currently use .htaccess to redirect mobile traffic to my mobile site, and that works great.  However I have discovered that if someone with a touch device were to try and access a page on my server from either directly typing it in as a URL, or from an external link, it would redirect the user to the index page of my mobile site.

An example; I create a lot of slideshows for Realtors using SlideShowPro Director.  These slideshows are embeded in an HTML page I create.  I send the URL to my Realtors so they can access the slideshows, or link the URL to another site.  If someone using a touch device were to follow that link, the .htaccess file would detect the device and redirect them to the mobile index page, not to the slideshow page.  Obviously something is screwy with the way the file is configured.  The code for the file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.mainevideotours.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.mainevideotours.com [R,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate!!
-Keith

Comment: What kind of error or unexpected behavior are you getting? The rules look fine

Comment: As i mentioned, the file is redirecting any and all mobile traffic from any page on my website. I would like it to only redirect if someone tries accessing the root domain index file, www.mainevideotours.com/index.html, not any of the other pages on my domain.

Comment: The problem is, for example, if someone follows a link from another website to a slideshow page on my server and they are using a touch device, the file detects the device and redirects them to the mobile index page, so they never end up getting to the page they were trying to access.

Is there a way I can write my links so that they are unaffected by the .htaccess file? (www.example.com?m=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like it to only redirect if someone tries accessing the root domain index file, www.mainevideotours.com/index.html, not any of the other pages on my domain

Ah. It looks like you'll need to change your rule (the last line) to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(index.html)?$ http://m.mainevideotours.com [R,L]
```

This should cover both `/` and `/index.html`

Comment: Let me try that out! Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Jon Wouldn't it be better to use `[R=301,L]`? Just using `R` makes it a temporary redirect (302) which is not good for search engine rankings (see second message in [this thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1017.htm).

Comment: @ToddProuty This is a redirect for a mobile device, not an identical page, if the redirect is 301, you wouldn't be able to arbitrarily turn on or off the mobile version of the site as your browser would cache the redirect

Comment: @Jon Of course, sorry, I skipped to the answer with another purpose for redirecting in my mind. Fuzzy-minded Saturday.